# MongooseError: Model.findOneAndRemove() no longer accepts a callback

Tags: javascript, mongodb, server

```
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
var app = express()
var Data = require('./noteSchema')

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/newDB')

mongoose.connection.once("open", () => {
    console.log("Connected to DB!")
}).on("error", (error) => {
    console.log("Failed to connect"+ error)
})
app.post("/create", (req,res) => {
    var note = new Data ({
        
        note: req.get("note"),
        title: req.get("title"),
        date: req.get("date")
    })

    note.save().then( () => {
        
        if( note.isNew == false){
            console.log("Save data!")
            res.send("Saved data !")
        }else{
            console.log("Failed to save data !")
        }
    })
})
app.get('/fetch', (req, res) => {    
    Data.find({}).then( (DBitems) => {
        res.send(DBitems )
    })  
})
app.post("/delete" , ( req , res ) =>{
    Data.findOneAndRemove({
        _id: req.get("id")   
    }, function(err) {
        console.log("Failed"+ err)
    })
    res.send("Deleted!")
})
var server = app.listen (8081,"192.x.x.x",()=>{
    console.log("server is running !")
})
```

i tried many things but cant figure out what to do

there seems to be a change in new update

> error msg:MongooseError: Model.findOneAndRemove() no longer accepts a callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following the error,
you just need to change your code to use `async` function
that would be like:

```
app.post("/delete" , async ( req , res ) =>{
    await Data.findOneAndRemove({
        _id: req.get("id")   
    })
    res.send("Deleted!")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is correct but it does not handles the error part which was part of the callback. The improvised code can be:

```
app.post('/delete', async (req,res) => {
  try {
    await  Data.findOneAndDelete({ _id: req.get("id") })
    res.send("Deleted!!")
  } catch(error) {   
    console.log("Failed" + error)
  }     
})
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).